# How to delete Skype history?

Tags: skype, chat-history

How to delete Skype history?

I saw two methods declared: (1) delete Skype application data and/or (2) reinstall Skype.

But both methods are compromised by an idea and saying, that Skype history is (maybe partially) stored on Skype server.

If so, then History will resurrect after both actions.

So, my question is: how to really delete history?

Also I need some explanations about the cases where history was resurrecting. For example, this can be because parallel client was holding history...

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings - Apps, find Skype in list of installed apps and click on clear data button and clear cache.

> Also I need some explanations about the cases where history was resurrecting. For example, this can be because parallel client was holding history...

Skype archives your chats for you and stores them locally on your computer (or device), if you have enabled this option. Chat histories are not stored anywhere on the Skype network. [source](http://blogs.skype.com/2006/07/06/managing-your-chat-history/)

Comment: This is not true. Try to login to Skype under one name from different computers simultaneously. You will get your history on both.

Comment: That's right. Because skype stores history locally on computer, if you receive for example skype message, any computer that is on will store the data locally. And if you was offline, then you will receive messages from users you had communicated on other computers if these users are online.

Comment: No-no, you will also see some messages, which came BEFORE computer was online. Ones, another computer received.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Android phone, you can follow the below steps for deleting Skype history,

Settings >> Applications >> Manage Applications >> Downloaded Apps/All >> Skype >> Clear Data

For your PC,

Open Skype >> Tools >> Options >> Privacy >> Clear History

Hope this helps!

Comment: The questioner doubts whether that really clears the history, because "Skype history is (maybe partially) stored on Skype server". Can you offer some justification for why that idea might be wrong?